# equivilent to c# SortCompare in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

I found the following event that I want to use in my asp.net app.

```
private void grid_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            if (e.RowIndex1 == this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1) 
                e.Handled = true; 
            if (e.RowIndex2 == this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) 
                e.Handled = true; 
            return; 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            ex.ToString(); 
        } 
    }
```

Basically it checks to see if it is the last row and if it is it does not sort. Hence sorting all rows besides the last one.

How can I implement this into my asp.net page in which I have a GridView. This event was written for C# desktop apps and I cannot seem to find the equivalent for asp.net

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the "OnSorting" event to your GridView tag in the aspx markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" runat="server" />
```

Then implement gridview_Sorting()

```
protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   //Perform manual sort as you have described
}
```

Yes, you do not have the row by row sort checks/convenience... rather you must override and perform your own sort method.  This is one of the many limitations of the web vs desktop components as far as I know.

Comment: ugh. not the answer I was hoping for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP .net the grid view has template fields. You can make your last row into a template footer, to make a Total row for example. Using this method you will still be able to sort, but your total row will stay at the bottom.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx